# неверный метод `posts_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Есть 2 таблицы,User и Post,и на странице пользователя пытаюсь сделать form_for для ввода post'а и дальнейшего вывода на экран. мой `profile_controller.rb`

```
def show
@user = current_user
@post = current_user.posts.build
end
```

Вот `post_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

respond_to :html, :js

def index
@post = Post.all
end

def show
end

def new
@post = Post.new
end

def edit
end

def create
@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully   created.' }
    format.js{}
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update!(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private
def set_post
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:comment,:user_id,:created_at)
end
```

routes.rb:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
 root "welcome#index"

 # путь к profile/index
 get "/profile" => "profile#show", as: :profile
```

И собственно форма,на которую он ругается,c переменной @post `show.html`:

```
   <%= form_for @post do |f| %>

        <div class="one">
          <%= f.label :comment %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :comment, autofocus: true%>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-link"><br />
          <%= f.submit "Send" %>
        </div>
```

Есть подозрения,что это методы в post_controller которые неправильно работают и посылают меня на post_path,но не вгоняю что именно.

Comment: routes.rb фстудию!

Comment: изменил,в вопросе добавил роуты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет роутов для `PostController`.

Нужно добавить в `routes.rb`

```
resources :post
```

[Вот документация](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) для более тонкой настройки.

**UPD:**
Как, совершенно справедливо, подсказывают, для ресурсных контроллеров нужно выбирать названия во множественном числе. Роуты создадутся и так, но вот `FormBuilder` может этого не оценить. Так что имеет смысл переименовать класс контроллера в `PostsController`, соотвественно, файл в котором он лежит переименовать в `posts_controller.rb`.
Роуты, тогда примут вид:

```
resources :posts
```

Comment: Тут ещё немного беда с тем, что в Rails принято в названии контроллера и аргументе `resources` использовать множественное число. Я сначала поправил было ответ, а потом заметил, что в вопросе тоже есть такая дыра.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо. Дополнил.